# Returning a Dataframe of each group with a condition of max value of a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I have one dataframe (this one is a demo for explaining the problem), in which I have to group datas with same same row values of 1 particular column let's say Company name.

We have 3 As and 4 Bs. So there are 2 different entities so in output. I need 2 rows for A and B but with the condition that I need the data of that company whose MPG value is maximum.

So the output should look like:

```
A A2 2020 Auto 2.0 67.3
B B4 2021 Manual 1.5 83.1
```

I have tried all the possible things with groupby method but couldn't get the result.

I have tried:

```
new_df = pd.groupby(["Company"])["MPG"].max()
```

And also,

```
new_df = pd.groupby(["Company"]).max(["MPG"])
```

But only getting the series in return. Not the Dataframe

[image]

Comment: `df.sort_values('MPG',  ascending=False).groupby('Company').head(1)`

Comment: Thank you so much man. You saved my night. I was stressed out looking for the solution. Thanks a lot. Bless you @Psidom